# how WCF Webservices can be tested locally from android emulator?

Tags: android, wcf, android-emulator

> how can WCF Webservices be tested locally from android emulator?
>   is that by using the IP as  10.0.2.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot consume the service located locally, You may have to setup the DNS in you device or emulator, so that it can resolve the host name.The way is

**Settings -> Wireless Control -> Mobile Networks -> Access Point Names**

click on the one that is in use, fill in Proxy and Port with your DNS server.

[Access local service](http://www.gitshah.com/2011/02/android-fixing-no-internet-connection.html?showComment=1344511892100#c5603712472032022102)

Comment: :Actullly i can access my **WCF**service in from emulator browser.Butwhen But its not gettind any result when i gave the corresponding URL in my android program .wen i clicks on the button to view results as a list from the service, its being closed.